# c# How to get count of value in a List based on value in another List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I understand how you can get the count of a List where each value might have some number.  For example if I wanted the number of times a value was equal to 1 in "ListA" I would do the following:

```
int countOf1=ListA.Count(x => x ==1);
```

If I have several Lists, and I want to get the count of ListB where ListA is equal to some value, how can I modify the above command to do so?

To illustrate the question, I will show a picture in a spreadsheet of what this would look like.  In the pic, you can see ListA and ListB will always have the same number of values, as I want information on each row to be an 'observation' of sorts.

I could do this with a loop, but I would like my script to be a bit simpler.  I also realize for this example, I could just get the count of ListA where the value is equal to 1.  But I will have some other things I want to do in the future like compute averages, percentiles or other aggregations on ListB, where ListA is equal to some value.

Is this possible to do?

[Picture of Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS225.jpg)

Comment: To clarify... for every `ListA[x] == 1`, you want to get `ListB[x]`?

Comment: Yes, the best way to describe would be if I wanted to get the average of all the values in ListB WHERE ListA==1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like what you want to do is join list A onto list B.  You don't specify in your question how the two lists should be joined but based on your image I am guessing you want to do it by the index - i.e. A[0] to B[0], A[1] to B[1], etc.  If that is the case you can use `Zip`.  Then if you wanted to take the average of B where A equals 1, for example, you could do the following:

```
ListA
.Zip(
    ListB,
    (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b })
.Where(x => x.A == 1)
.Average(x => x.B);
```